# Selected select pseudo-class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to apply styles to `select` input elements only if they have an `option:checked`. It seems to me that this isn't possible using css only. (I am aware that there's no parent selector)

```
select:pseudo-class-here {
    background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: Why select tag has option checked? Did you mean selected state?

Comment: Share your code here

Comment: Yes i mean selected state.

Comment: show us what you have tried?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_checked.asp

Comment: What do you mean by `selected state` ?

Comment: @HienNguyen — The name of the CSS pseudo-class is `:checked`, not `:selected`

Comment: "I'm not asking if there's a parent selector!" — Yes, you are. Your question was much clearer before you started editing it, but you are asking to select a `<select>` element when one of the `<option>` elements inside it is `:checked` … which would require a parent combinator.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for a combination of `required`, and `:valid`/`:invalid` pseudo classes …?

Comment: @Quentin It could be solved if there's an `parent` selector indeed, but wouldn't it be better if there's an `:selected` pseudo class on the `select` element?

Comment: @Quisse did you tried this way  `option:checked { Your style }` or `select option:selected`?

Comment: @soorapadman — Those would select the option element not the select element.

Comment: @Quentin, I now get why the pseudo class isn't possible. A `select` element always has an `option` selected. Maybe unmark this question as duplicate so i can answer this?

Comment: "I want to apply styles to select elements only if they have a selected state" quite a funny one IMO since select always selecting something if they had option.

Comment: @Mukyuu yes that was the answer I was looking for.

Comment: @Quisse – `<select multiple>` can have any number of options selected, including 0. (If the question was specifically about non-multiple selects, then it makes no sense at all, and should just be deleted and not answered with "The question makes no sense at all")

Comment: @Quentin Interesting, so u still think this is duplicate to 'Is there a CSS parent selector'? The answers don't look like it and to me it seems that this is a question about the select element and not about css selectors in general. Too bad.

Comment: Not the select element does get selected, individual options do. So you can not use `select:selected`, but you _would_ need something to make the formatting of the parent (select) dependent on the state of children (options) … and that pretty much closes the circle to the duplicate, which explains that that possibility does not currently exist in CSS.

Comment: @04FS so I'm the only one thinking that your answer is a much clearer explanation to the question than marking as duplicate?

Comment: @Quisse That is because your question still isn't clear. For all we know you need `:focus-within` instead of `:selected`. Rather than complaining about the closure, edit the question to make it obvious what you're asking.

Comment: @MrLister thanks for the constructive feedback. I'll try to be more obvious in my questioning.

Comment: @Quisse OK. One problem was that there are distinct answers for <select> and <select multiple>, another that "select with a selected option" is not the same as "select with an option that has the `selected` attribute", so it's good to have cleared that up

Comment: @MrLister indeed it's good. Anything else not clear/I can improve in my question? I already know the answer & have an assumption what the reason is. The only point I'm continuing this thread is to prevent others from running into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is no such pseudo-class. Could be because a regular `select` element always has an `option` selected. This is not the case on `select multiple` elements.